# clearing caches individually (product, category, homepage, etc)

Tags: category, admin, adminhtml, cache

is it possible to clear things like the products, category, homepage cache individually?  If so, how?

Comment: What is your cache backend? Are you using something like APC or Redis; stock file cache?

Comment: @RickBuczynski Redis.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

EDIT: I should note that this isn't possible via Magento admin interface. You'd have to build/find an extension to add this functionality, else write a script with what I describe below.

-

### Cleaning Cache Tags

Magento wraps all communication with the cache backend with `Mage_Core_Model_Cache -> Mage::getSingleton('core/cache')`.

If you look at this class you can talk to the backend to remove cached entries using `Mage_Core_Model_Cache::clean(array $tags)`. These cache tags should be given for your major Magento blocks. For example, look at `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product`:

```
class Mage_Catalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Entity code.
     * Can be used as part of method name for entity processing
     */
    const ENTITY                 = 'catalog_product';

    const CACHE_TAG              = 'catalog_product';
    protected $_cacheTag         = 'catalog_product';
    protected $_eventPrefix      = 'catalog_product';
    protected $_eventObject      = 'product';
    protected $_canAffectOptions = false;
    ...
```

The `const CACHE_TAG` is what you'll be looking for. You can clear all product block cache using this tag, like so:

`Mage::getSingleton('core/cache')->clean(array('catalog_product'));`

<strike>As for categories, I don't know of any cache tags implemented for their view classes</strike> As Si Griffiths noted, you can use the `catalog_category` tags.

As for the homepage, which is a CMS page, the cache tag is actually derived from the CMS page model, `Mage_Cms_Model_Page::CACHE_TAG`. The block abstract (`Mage_Core_Block_Abstract`) has a method that lets you port over cache tags from a model (see `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract::addModelTags`). This pattern is also used for categories and products.

### Working with FPC

As mentioned by both Si and myself, FPC adds a layer of complexity to dealing with cache that can't be resolved just by cleaning cache tags. FPC is a *separate* layer of caching that is stored separately.

To flush ALL FPC, you can use the following:

```
Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->flush()
```

Combining that with the above tag cleaning method, you should be able to programmatically get product/category pages to reflect changes. But this FPC command will clear FPC abroad. This is where things like "hole-punching" come into play, but I would say it's beyond the scope of this question and better left to others who have already explained it well:

> http://www.kingletas.com/2012/09/how-does-magento-full-page-cache-works.html
>   https://stackoverflow.com/a/9125519/1442685

Comment: is it possible to find my own specific homepage cache tag from, for example, printing it on the homepage somewhere in our dev enviro?  Or if we have a custom homepage that isn't controlled with a cms?

Comment: If it's not generated as a CMS page then you are likely using a custom block and template that you want to clear. If your block class doesn't explicitly add cache data (see [this article](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-block-caching/)) then it shouldn't be getting cached. If you're using full-page caching, however, that's another story, and you'll have to leverage some kind of hole-punching technique in addition to the above to get the job done.

Comment: If you want to see if your block is using cache tags, just call `var_dump($this->getCacheTags())` within your template. This method comes from `Mage_Core_Block_Abstract` and should be available to you wherever you are.

Comment: does this Mage::getSingleton('core/cache')->clean(array('catalog_product')); call the redis clearing function?

Comment: how would I programatically clear the fpc cache with redis?

Comment: @easymoden00b Yes, cleaning cache tags using the core cache model will call on Redis to clean the tags you supply. Now to programatically clear FPC, you should be able to call `Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->flush()` -- this process will work similarly to the core cache model, but with the added step of loading a different backend as you may have configured in `app/etc/local.xml`

Comment: @easymoden00b given that you've added bounty, are you still looking for help with the original question? For example you never asked about FPC initially. So did the above cache cleaning methods help you for product, category, and homepage cleaning?

Comment: I still can't seem to clear the product page or the category page cache individually -- given that I have FPC on.

Comment: @easymoden00b I've updated my answer with the most info I can provide, since the comment thread is getting too long.

Answer (score 2):

Programatically as mentioned above by Rick cache entires can be removed by tag.  Most are constructed by tag+id with a slight exception being CMS pages.

So for example:

Products: 'catalog_product' would remove all or 'catalog_product_someidnumeric' would remove that particular id.
Categories: 'catalog_category'
CMS pages: 'cms_page'

Now that relates to the block cache.  FPC in enterprise by default is an all or nothing approach from what I remember.  You can clean the lot or nothing.  Now extensions for redis or varnish make targeted FPC cleans better but by default you can only clean the lot.

A little tip is the cache tag sometimes matches the class applied to the body tag :)

Comment: If I were able to create more checkboxes for things like the categories or products or this homepage cache would I be able to clear these individually?

Comment: how would I programatically clear the fpc cache with redis?

Comment: You can clear FPC this way too. Let's say my homepage is CMS page id is 2. I can run the following command to flush it Enterprise_PageCache_Model_Cache::getCacheInstance()->clean('CMS_PAGE_2');